# Implementing the Square Non-linearity (SQNL) activation function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backend, keras-layer, activation-function

I have been trying to implement the square non-linearity activation function function as a custom activation function for a keras model. It's the 10'th function on this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function.

I tried using the keras backend but i got nowhere with the multiple if else statements i require so i also tried using the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
def square_nonlin(x):
    orig = x
    x = tf.where(orig >2.0, (tf.ones_like(x)) , x)
    x = tf.where(0.0 <= orig <=2.0, (x - tf.math.square(x)/4), x)
    x = tf.where(-2.0 <= orig < 0, (x + tf.math.square(x)/4), x)
    return tf.where(orig < -2.0, -1, x)
```

As you can see there's 4 different clauses i need to evaluate. But when i try to compile the Keras model i still get the error:

```py
Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed
```

Could anyone help me to get this working in Keras? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to replace the comparison statements by functions such as `tf.greater(x, 2.0)`.

Comment: I have tried this and it still gives the same error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just started a week ago digging into tensorflow and am actively playing around with different activation functions. I think I know what two of your problems are. In your second and third assignments you have compound conditionals you need to put them in under `tf.logical_and`. The other problem you have is that the last `tf.where` on the return line returns a `-1` which is not a vector, which tensorflow expects. I haven't tried the function with Keras, but in my "activation function" tester this code works.

```
def square_nonlin(x):
    orig = x
    x = tf.where(orig >2.0, (tf.ones_like(x)) , x)
    x = tf.where(tf.logical_and(0.0 <= orig, orig <=2.0), (x - tf.math.square(x)/4.), x)
    x = tf.where(tf.logical_and(-2.0 <= orig, orig < 0), (x + tf.math.square(x)/4.), x)
    return tf.where(orig < -2.0, 0*x-1.0, x)
```

As I said I'm new at this so to "vectorize" `-1`, I multiplied the `x` vector by `0` and subtracted `-1` which produces a array filled with `-1` of the right shape. Perhaps one of the more seasoned tensorflow practioners can suggest the proper way to do that.

Hope this helps.

BTW, `tf.greater` is equivlent to `tf.__gt__` which means that `orig > 2.0` expands under the covers in python to `tf.greater(orig, 2.0)`.

Just a follow up. I tried it with the MNIST demo in Keras and the activation function works as coded above.

UPDATE:

The less hacky way to "vectorize" `-1` is to use the `tf.ones_like` function

so replace the last line with

```
   return tf.where(orig < -2.0, -tf.ones_like(x), x)
```

for a cleaner solution